# The calculated Robustscaler in sklearn seems not right

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-preprocessing

I tried the Robustscaler in sklearn, and found the results are not the same as the formula.

The formula of the Robustscaler in sklearn is:

[image: Figure 1. The formula to calculate Robustscaler]

I have a matrix shown as below:

[image: Figure 2. The test matrix]

I test the first data in feature one (row one and column one). The scaled value should be `(1-3)/(5.5-1.5) = -0.5`. However, the result from the sklearn is `-0.67`. Does anyone know where the calculation is not correct?

The code using sklearn is as below:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
x=[[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7],[7,8,9,10],[2,1,1,1]]
scaler = RobustScaler(quantile_range=(25.0, 75.0),with_centering=True)
x_new = scaler.fit_transform(x)
print(x_new)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the RobustScaler [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.RobustScaler.html) (emphasis added):

> Centering and scaling happen **independently on each feature** by computing the relevant statistics on the samples in the training set.

i.e. the median and IQR quantities are calculated **per column**, and not for the whole array.

Having clarified that, let's calculate the scaled values for your first column manually:

```
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array([1, 4, 7, 2]) # your 1st column here

q75, q25 = np.percentile(x1, [75 ,25])
iqr = q75 - q25

x1_med = np.median(x1)

x1_scaled = (x1-x1_med)/iqr
x1_scaled
# array([-0.66666667,  0.33333333,  1.33333333, -0.33333333])
```

which is the same with the first column of your own `x_new`, as calculated by scikit-learn:

```
# your code verbatim:
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
x=[[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7],[7,8,9,10],[2,1,1,1]]
scaler = RobustScaler(quantile_range=(25.0, 75.0),with_centering=True)
x_new = scaler.fit_transform(x)
print(x_new)
# result
[[-0.66666667 -0.375      -0.35294118 -0.33333333]
 [ 0.33333333  0.375       0.35294118  0.33333333]
 [ 1.33333333  1.125       1.05882353  1.        ]
 [-0.33333333 -0.625      -0.82352941 -1.        ]]

np.all(x1_scaled == x_new[:,0])
# True
```

Similarly for the rest of the columns (features) - you need to calculate separately the median and IQR values for each one of them before scaling them.

**UPDATE** (after comment):

As pointed out in the Wikipedia entry on [quartiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile#Discrete_distributions):

> For discrete distributions, there is no universal agreement on selecting the quartile values

See also the relevant reference, [*Sample quantiles in statistical packages*](https://www.amherst.edu/media/view/129116/original):

> There are a large number of different definitions used for sample quantiles in statistical computer packages

Digging into the documentation of [`np.percentile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) used here, you'll see that there are no less that five (5) different methods of interpolation, and not all of them produce identical results (see also the 4 different methods demonstrated in the Wikipedia entry linked just above); here is a quick demonstration of these methods and their results in the `x1` data defined above:

```
np.percentile(x1, [75 ,25]) # interpolation='linear' by default
# array([4.75, 1.75])

np.percentile(x1, [75 ,25], interpolation='lower')
# array([4, 1])

np.percentile(x1, [75 ,25], interpolation='higher')
# array([7, 2])

np.percentile(x1, [75 ,25], interpolation='midpoint')
# array([5.5, 1.5])

np.percentile(x1, [75 ,25], interpolation='nearest')
# array([4, 2])
```

Apart from the fact that there are no two methods producing identical results, it should also be apparent that the definition you are using in your own calculations corresponds to `interpolation='midpoint'`, while the default Numpy method is `interpolation='linear'`. And as Ben Reiniger correctly points out in the comments below, what is actually used in the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13af77c76e150b753485c662b7c52a41a2/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py#L1376) of RobustScaler is [`np.nanpercentile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanpercentile.html) (a variation pf `np.percentile` I have used here that is able to handle `nan` values) with the default `interpolation='linear'` setting.

Comment: Hi @desertnaut,
Thanks for the answer. I still have a little question about q75 and q25. The first column is [1,4,7,2]. The q25 should be the median of the first two elements of this array, which is (1+2)/2 = 1.5. And, the q75 should be the median of the last two elements, which is (4+7)/2 = 5.5. Then iqr is 5.5-1.5=4. The median is (2+4)/2=3. Then x_scale is (1-3)/(5.5-1.5)=-0.5. The difference between this one and sklearn's is for the parameters: q25 and q75.
For my calculation of iqr: it is referenced to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range
Hope your further suggestions.

Comment: Just to note: RobustScaler calls `numpy.nanpercentile`, [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13af77c76e150b753485c662b7c52a41a2/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py#L1376), leaving the interpolation to the default.

Comment: @desertnaut Thanks for the update. If the RobustScaler is replaced by Normalizer, the x_sacle I calculated is still not the same as the sklearn's results. The formula I applied is x_i/||x||_2. For example, the first element of first feature (column) is 1. The second norm of the first column is sqrt(1+16+49+4)=8.3666. The x_scale for this point is 1/8.3666=0.1195. However, the result using Normalizer in sklearn is 0.18257419. What's the reason for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BenReiniger the code is given as below:

from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
x=[[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7],[7,8,9,10],[2,1,1,1]]
scaler = Normalizer()
x_new = scaler.fit_transform(x)
print(x_new)

Comment: @ZH.Yang `Normalizer` operates on rows, not columns.